# error when unzip apk file in ant

Tags: android, ant, unzip

I use ant to unzip an apk file, but it occurred an error like this:

```
<unzip src="test.apk" dest="testdir" >
```

error message:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: data starting at 0 is in unknown format

i googled it, and add attribute encoding="native-encoding" , it still error.
great thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

ok,finally I wrote a custom ant task using java ziputil to unzip an apk files. It does work well.

Comment: I am stuck with the same issue.. My java ziputil also fail .can you please share your code? or give any direction